# Is this point a saddle point?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> $$z=x^3+y^3-4xy$$

$z_{x}: 3x^2-4y$

$z_{y}: 3y^2-4x$

the points are: $(0,0),(\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3}),(\frac{4}{3},-\frac{4}{3})$

$z_{xx}: 6x$

$z_{yy}: 6y$

$D:36xy-16$

I know that $(\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3})$ is a minimum.

But for $(\frac{4}{3},-\frac{4}{3})$ $D<0$ shouldn't it be a saddle point? if I get $z_{xx}<0$ or $z_{xx}>0$ do $z_{yy}$ must be the same for minimum or maximum?

Comment: Where is $z_{xy}?$

Comment: On $\mathbb R^2$, if the determinant is **negative**, then the Hessian has a positive and a negative eigenvalue. So that point must be a saddle point.

Comment: What about $z_{xy} = s? $ If pure second derivatives are $(z_{xx} = r,  z_{yy} = t )$ , then need to consider $ ( rt -s^2) $

Comment: Sorry, added $z_{xy}$

Comment: I don't see that (4/3,-4/3) is a critical pt.

Answer (score 2):

it must be $$z_y=4y^3-4x=0$$ try to start the problem again
with $$3x^2-4y=0$$ and $$3y^2-4x=0$$ we get $$(x,y)=(0,0)$$ or $$x=4/3,y=4/3$$
$$(x,y)=(0,0)$$ is a saddle point and $$(x,y)=(4/3,4/3)$$ is a minimum

Comment: Sorry miswritten it, I have fixed it know

Comment: I need to be very careful with the numbers